# Java Plugin for Minecraft - Changing command

Tags: java, minecraft

So I am editing a plugin that is for minecraft spigot.

In a decompiler / debugger this is what shows up for 'FlyCommand.class' under me.twister915.ffly

https://pastebin.com/KB3jLX7S

Here is what appears in my intellij project for the  same file.

https://pastebin.com/kqX3DzTu

I am trying to change the part for

```
  public FlyCommand()
  {
    super("fly");
  }
```

I assume from intellij this is where it  needs to be edited. But I can't figure out how to change so people don't use the command "/fly" ingame. I rather change it to something like "/vfly"

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: 1. Why does it need to be "vfly" 2. Are you sure the plugin license allows you to do this? 3. You need to use the source code and edit that (or decompile everything into source code with a decompiler), then re-compile it

Comment: I just don't want it to overwrite another command with another plugin which is /fly. That is what its currently doing, I want it to take 2nd priority. I assume the best way to do this is changing the command. Also I have decompiled with jd-gui and then saved all the sources and imported it into intellij. @SocraticPhoenix

Comment: Hmm... this would probably be better suited for the bukkit forums... anyway if you really want to change it, just change the "fly" text to "vfly" (is the file extension .java or .class?)

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the `CommandPreProcessEvent` [(javadocs)](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent.html) and treat the event anyway you want.

```
@EventHandler
public void onCmdPreProcess(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent e) {
    if (e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("/" + "command") {
        e.setCancelled(true);    //Treat command in your way
    }
}
```